# onDrop event forwards to url but only in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
            <style>
            .canvas {
                position:relative;
                height:550px;
                width:400px;
                background:Yellow url("http://www.mapstop.co.uk/images/uploaded/lrg_wg2668.6a40d0d.jpg") no-repeat;
            }
            .canvas img {
                position:absolute;
            }
            </style>
            <div class="toolbar">
            <span>Drag...</span>
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoEOi.png" alt="" title="" />
            <img src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Thermometer_Snowflake.png" alt="" title="" />
            <img src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Overcast.png" alt="" title="" />
            <img src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Night_Rain.png" alt="" title="" />
            </div>
            <div class="canvas"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $toolbar = $(".toolbar");
                var $tools = $toolbar.find("img");

                //define drag and drop handlers
                $toolbar.on("dragstart", "img", onDrag);

                $(".canvas").on({
                    dragenter: false,
                    dragover: false,
                    drop: onDrop
                });

                //handle commencement of drag
                function onDrag(e) {

                    console.log("onDrag");
                }

                //handle drop
                function onDrop(e) {

                    //console.log("OnDrop");
                    //console.log(e.clientX);
                    //console.log(e.clientY);
                    //console.log(e.originalEvent);
                }
            });
            </script>
```

When I drop an image I get forwarded for some reason to http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Sunny.png but only in FireFox. Both Chrome and IE seems to take the intended behavior which says to do nothing right now. Perhaps someone may know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying handlers for drag enter and drag over and add `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();` to your handlers.

Comment: That didn't really have any effect. The code still forwards to a URL but only in FireFox. This is very odd.

Comment: I have very similar code I can go back to that looks very much the same but doesn't forward to a URL in FireFox. There must be some detail causing this I am unaware of right now.

Comment: @user2209542 try adding     `e.preventDefault();`
   and `e.stopPropagation();` to your handlers

Comment: That did the trick. I've seen those functions before. I'm in search of a good reference actually when it comes to this type of drag and drop.